# SpringRunner unable to detect configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring-boot application for which am trying to create unit testcases. Below is the code that I am trying to run, I don't have any configuration file that I have (used only annotations) so the main class that loads all the configuration is `ElastSearchBootApplication` class. For some reason I see the below error.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.somename")
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class ElastSearchBootApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElastSearchBootApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElastSearchBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ElastSearchLogLevel logsSearch;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 120000)
public void scheduledSearchLogs() {
        ...
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ElastSearchBootApplication.class)
public class LogSearchTest {

    @Mock
    private RestHighLevelClient client;
    @Mock
      private ExecutorService ALERT_POOL;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
          client = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
        ALERT_POOL = mock(ExecutorService.class);

        try {
            when(client.search(anyObject())).thenReturn(getResponse());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // I see NullPointerException but both the instances are available here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doNothing().when(ALERT_POOL.invokeAll(anyObject()));
    }
```

I see the below error when trying to run the spring-boot test :

```
org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.somename.search.LogSearchTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFO: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.somename.search.LogSearchTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils detectDefaultConfigurationClasses
INFO: Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.somename.search.LogSearchTest]: LogSearchTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
```

1. I see that `@SpringBootTest` is used for integration tests, so can I use it for unit tests ? If I remove it then I get another set of exception that looks similar though. I would be more interested in running this testcase without `SpringBootTest`
2. Why my test case say some configuration is missing. The samples online talk about xml files which I don't have. So what am I missing here ?
3. Can I dynamically pass the value for `fixedRate` from `Environment` and put it like `@Scheduled(fixedRate = ${some.value.defined})`

**UPDATE**

I can run the test but without the proper order. Ideally i expect `setUp` to run first. But its running second. Also the line `when(client.search(anyObject())).thenReturn(getResponse());` is failing and i dont get the reason...

Comment: Replace your `@RunWith` with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` on the test class. You don't need `@ ContextConfiguration` and `@SpringBootTest` for the unit test class.

Comment: Without `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ElastSearchBootApplication.class)` configuration will not be detected. However I will update the code now to show you the latest. For some reasonmy mocking is failing at `when(client.search(anyObject())).thenReturn(getResponse());`

Comment: Also, are you trying to mock the elasticsearch client? Here it says that it can't be mocked https://discuss.elastic.co/t/resthighlevelclient-mocking/123027

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to add the annotation @ContextConfiguration to your test class to specify  configuration file.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ElastSearchBootApplication.class)
```

Comment: I have added it now it goes a little further now instead of starting with `setup()` it directly runs my testcases inspite of `@Before` on it.

Comment: Where you added this annotation?

Comment: Nope, the junit `@Before` is not working so I removed the code in `setup` and put in test menthod itself, which solves my one of the problems. as I said the code within try block is throwing exception for some reason when the code goes inside elasticsearch API I get a `NullPointerException`

Comment: This works, but not sure why it wont detect groovy package.  com.y.u.n.x.api.acceptance.tests.acceptance com.y.u.n.x.acceptance.tests.acceptance --> My mail class resides here

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LogSearchTest {

  @MockBean
  private RestHighLevelClient client;
  @MockBean
  private ExecutorService ALERT_POOL;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
   try {
        when(client.search(anyObject())).thenReturn(getResponse());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // I see NullPointerException but both the instances are available here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doNothing().when(ALERT_POOL.invokeAll(anyObject()));
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Previously this is what I had when I started off with the issue. I have actually updated the code now. Its the issue with `SpringBootTest` I think, somehow not reading test ENV and its suppose to run `setUp` first.

Comment: If you wann using `@ContextConfiguration` you should create class `@Configuration` where you declare all required beans in your case : repeat configs from main lcass `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.somename")` and `@EnableScheduling` .  You got error "Could not detect default configuration..." because of `ElastSearchBootApplication`  is not `@Configuration` class.  Good topic about it: https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles

Comment: Since I added `@ContextConfiguration` my testcase is able to autowire things its not expecting a separate `@Configuration` and I don't need `@EnableScheduling`.

Comment: If you wanna minimal context better choice is using separate configuration class, otherwise for example you will scan whole package via `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.somename")` instead of just create one required service for test. What expected result of your questions???? Maybe you have example on github it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Note, in Junit5 you'll replace @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class). So you'll have:

```
 @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
 @SpringBootTest
 public class Your {
 ...
```